# Not able to switch off batch norm layers for faster-rcnn (PyTorch)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, batch-normalization, faster-rcnn

I'm trying to switch off batch norm layers in a faster-rcnn model for evaluation mode.

I'm doing a sanity check atm:

```
@torch.no_grad()
def evaluate_loss(model, data_loader, device):
    val_loss = 0
    model.train()
    for images, targets in data_loader:
        # check that all layers are in train mode
        # for name, module in model.named_modules():
        #     if hasattr(module, 'training'):
        #         print('{} is training {}'.format(name, module.training))
        #         # set bn layers to eval
        for module in model.modules():
            if isinstance(module, torch.nn.BatchNorm2d):
                module.eval()
        # bn layers are now in eval
        for name, module in model.named_modules():
            if hasattr(module, 'training'):
                print('{} is training {}'.format(name, module.training))
```

However, all the batch norm layers are still in training mode. When I replace it with for example Conv2d, I get the expected behaviour of `False`. Here is an example snippet of the output:

```
backbone.body.layer4.0.conv1 is training True
backbone.body.layer4.0.bn1 is training True
backbone.body.layer4.0.conv2 is training True
backbone.body.layer4.0.bn2 is training True
backbone.body.layer4.0.conv3 is training True
backbone.body.layer4.0.bn3 is training True
```

Why is this happening? What can I do to switch off these layers? I have tried this with all variations of batch norm as provided by torch.nn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after further investigation and after printing out all modules provided by the faster-rcnn, instead of `BatchNorm2d`, `FrozenBatchNorm2d` is used by the pretained model.

Furthermore, unlike what's currently stated by the documentation, you must call `torchvision.ops.misc.FrozenBatchNorm2d` instead of `torchvision.ops.FrozenBatchNorm2d`.

Additionally, as the layers are already frozen, there is no need to "switch off" these layers thus `model.eval()` is probably not required.